# Dart runtime type comparison with 'is' keyword

Tags: dart, types

I know the `is` keyword can be used to check the type of a instance. But when I try it with a `Type` variable instead of directly using the type with `is` like this,

```dart
final Type myType = String;
print('MyString' is myType); //ERROR
```

it throws the following error.

> The name 'myType' isn't a type and can't be used in an 'is' expression
>   - line 2

But if I use the `runtimeType` and `==` like this, it works fine.

```dart
final Type myType = String;
print('MyString'.runtimeType == myType); //TRUE
```

Can you please explain the reason for this behavior?

Comment: https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/945

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the comment by @julemand101, there is a [github issue on the official dart repository](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/945). Apparently the implementation of runtime type comparison with `is` introduces a **significant cost of code size**.

> In general the only argument against this is based on the estimated
>   code size impact, because compiler looses a good way to estimate which
>   type checks can occur in the program - and thus can no longer throw
>   away some of the metadata associated with the class hierarchy.
>   @rakudrama has done experiment for dart2js to estimate approximate
>   impact and saw some non negligible costs in terms of the code size.